# Implementing site-specific plugins in a Python application

Tags: python, subclass, alias

I'm writing a Python application that will be installed at multiple sites. At each of those sites it needs to interface to other software with a different api at each site but all logically doing the same thing.

My solution is to create a base Class that encapsulates the common logic and provides a single interface back to the main app, and then separate subclasses for each different site-specific api. The base class and subclasses would all be defined in an "interfaces" package deployed to each site alongside the main app. To ensure a common code base (for ease of deployment and maintenance) all sites would have identical code, both the main app package and the interfaces package.

My question is, how best to ensure the main app uses the correct subclass from the interfaces package?

My current thoughts are to have the main app call a "get_interface" function in the interfaces package which reads an ini file to identify which interface subclass is in use at that site and returns that subclass to the main app. Obviously this requires the ini file to be site-specific, but that is the only thing that would be.

Is that the best approach?

To add some more concrete info as requested:

The application is astronomy-related. It aims to automate a pipeline from target identification, through scheduling of telescope imaging sessions, to processing of the resultant images. It makes extensive use of Astropy and affiliated packages.

There are several areas where it needs to interface to other software. Eg:

1. Target Identification, where it gets target info from various astronomical databases through web services.
2. Platesolving, where it uploads image data to either local (Windows or Linux-based) applications or remote web services such as astrometry.net.
3. Imaging, where it needs to interface to commercial telescope/observatory control packages (eg ACP or ASA Sequence) to actually perform imaging sessions.

The logical interfaces are all pretty much identical within each of these areas so, in the above cases, I envisage 3 classes to provide abstractions, which would be implemented through sub classes specific to the target system I’m interfacing with.

I’m really just exploring the best design pattern for how to implement this in a way that keeps the core of the application totally isolated from the implementation of the interfaces to the other systems (as these change fairly frequently).

In a way it’s a bit like using device drivers. The core application needs to call for a service to be performed (not caring how that is achieved) with that call being routed to the “driver” (my appropriate interface sub class) which would be potentially different for each site implementation.

Comment: Going a bit more concrete but without too much details would probably be of help

Comment: IMHO there is never an absolute "best approach". Think about the issues arising from your approach and if they can be handled reasonably. If you deploy something that has to interface with many different APIs on different systems you either need to configure the use of the right interface or find a way to automate the API detection - however, automated detections may bring their own risks and corner cases and may behave in unexpected ways.